# Android studio unable to run the in my android device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

here guys I am new in android studio  just in the base , I tried to practice the android studio. I did not install virtual device  in my IDE  , I connect with my phone but my code is not running  , show this error anyone tell  me how to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: You can paste you screenshot directly here. Please edit your question for better readability. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
Check the Project code panel, and go to Gradle Scripts –> build.gradle file,

1. Change 3 places: compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, targetSdkVersion from 31 to 30.
2. You’ll notice a lightbulb hit occurring on modified lines, click and choose sync [to version 30]. The Android Studio will automatically download BuildTool V30 and change project settings.

**Solution 2**
I am Just changing these settings seems to work fine. I downloaded SDK version 30 from SDK manager. And my buld.gradle configuration is the same as below.

*compileSdkVersion 30
*buildToolsVersion “30.0.3”
*minSdkVersion 23
*targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: Why should the targetSdkVersion be reduced?

Answer (score 0):

As per the displayed error you need to uninstall revision 31 and then install it again.

To do this please follow these steps:

**Step 1** - Click on the SDK Manager Icon from the Task bar

[image]

**Step 2** - On the next dialog click the SDK Tools Tab as demonstrated below
[image]

**Step 3** - Click the CheckBox to uncheck the `Android SDK Build 31 Tools` as shown above

**Step 4** - Click ***Apply*** and ***OK*** buttons on the same dialog to uninstall.

**Step 5** - Repeat Step 1 and 2 above to open The SDK Manager Dialog from the Task Bar and then click on the 2nd Tab (SDK Tools)

**Step 6** - Click to check the empty checkbox as shown below:

[image]

**Step 7** - Click ***Apply*** and ***OK*** buttons on the same dialog to install the tools

This should help, let us know.

Answer (score -1):

Check the Project code panel, and go to Gradle Scripts → build.gradle file,

Change three places from 31 to 30: compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, and targetSdkVersion Like this

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "xxx.yyy.zzz"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
  
}
```

Comment: Why should the targetSdkVersion be reduced?